# How to pass environment variables from SAM cli to Lambda function code

Tags: python, aws-lambda, environment-variables

Is it possible to specify env variable in SAM so that it is available in Lambda function code (python)? I need to set different value for variable for stage deployments. I am able to set env variable in template file (yml) but not sure how to define it for different environments (dev, prod).

Comment: How are you deploying to your dev and prod environments?

Comment: I am using AWS SAM to deploy the Lambda. I have template.yml file which has Lambda function defined. It allows setting env variable under Environment > Variables tag. But the variable i want to set is different for diff environments. AWS Lambda console allows me to change the env variable after deployment. But I want to keep it automated during deployment itself.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can set the environment variable through a template parameter:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Parameters:
  Stage:
    Type: String
    AllowedValues:
      - dev
      - prod

Globals:
  Function:
    Environment:
      Variables:
        STAGE: !Ref Stage
```

Then in your deployment process, pass in the `Stage` parameter when creating/updating the stack from the SAM template. For example, if you're doing that via the [CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/index.html), use `--parameters ParameterKey=Stage,ParameterValue=prod`.

Comment: How do we use CLI to pass multiple parameters?

Comment: Hi @Milan, thank you for providing the above solution. I have a similar setup where i am using CodeCommit and Codepipeline using AWS SAM to deploy my lambda functions. My question is: How would we use the Parameters variables defined for the different environments in the code pipeline ?